# Unorganized table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with the table. They are not organized/neat and very confusing -> [image: http://i.imgur.com/1LLpQ2G.png]

The table has to look neat, understandable and not confusing like this -> [image: http://i.imgur.com/R3iqFzz.png] (this is how the table should look like)

This is what I have achieved so far (**See: OrderID 2**) -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QNgA.png

Below is the code

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Customer Contact</th>
                <th>Customer Email</th>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Menu Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Amount</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `order`");
            while($obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $orderDate = $obj['OrderDate'];
                $orderId = $obj['OrderID'];
                $totalAmount = $obj['OrderTotal'];
                $paymentStatus = $obj['PaymentStatus'];
                $customerId = $obj['CustomerID'];
                $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT CustomerName, CustomerContactNo, CustomerEmail FROM customer WHERE CustomerID=$customerId");
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                    $customerName = $row['CustomerName'];
                    $customerContactNo = $row['CustomerContactNo'];
                    $email = $row['CustomerEmail'];
                }

                $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ordermenu WHERE OrderID = $orderId");
                while($obj1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                    $menuId = $obj1['MenuID'];
                    $menuQty = $obj1['menuQty'];
                    $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE MenuID = $menuId");
                    $obj2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                    $name = $obj2['MenuName'];
                    $price = $obj2['MenuPrice'];
                ?>


            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $customerName;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $customerContactNo;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $email;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $orderId;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $orderDate;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
                <td>$<?php echo $price;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $menuQty;?></td>
                <td>$<?php echo $totalAmount;?></td>
                <td><a href="update_order.php?id=<?php echo $orderId;?>" color="green">Update</a></td>
            </tr>

                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Anyone help please.

Comment: I didn't mean the design has to look like the second picture. Some of the data in picture 1 are redundant and I want to eliminate redundant data for example order id 2 menu name, menu price and quantity. He bought 2 menu/food, each with different price and quantity.

Answer (score 1):

1. First get Customers From db
2. Foreach customer get Orders by customerID joined with ordermenu (on ordermenu.OrderID = order.OrderID) and joined with menu (on ordermenu.MenuID = menu.MenuID)

   ```
   <?php
   $customerQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerContactNo, CustomerEmail FROM customer;");
   while($customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customerQuery)) {
       $customerId = $customer['CustomerID'];
       $orderQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `order` o LEFT JOIN ordermenu om ON o.OrderID = om.OrderID LEFT JOIN menu m ON m.MenuID = om.MenuID WHERE o.CustomerID = $customerId");
       while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderQuery)) {
           // do something with your customer and order record
           // show in table for example
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: so i have to use "for" loop?

Comment: He is saying you need to move some columns out of the table into new tables and `JOIN` them. See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/

Comment: Not necessary, You can use "while" like in example I wrote.

Comment: What does `o` mean in `"SELECT * FROM order o LEFT JOIN ordermenu`?

Comment: and also `m`. Sorry I'm clueless

Comment: @samyo "o" and "m" are aliases for table: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Oh thanks but I get an error at this line `while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderQuery)) {`

Comment: You wrote that have an error at this line while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderQuery)) so show me what kind of error do yo have

Comment: well it says `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\campuslunchbox3\staff_update_order.php on line 168`. Line 168 is `while($customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customerQuery)) {` Do I have to put the word "AS" in the query?

Comment: This error talks You that query "SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerContactNo, CustomerEmail FROM customer" is bad and not returns mysqli_result but false. Please try use this query in your database (maybe in phpmyadmin) and try fix it.

Comment: oops sorry wrong line! my bad. Line 168 supposed to be `while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderQuery)) {` sorry again

Comment: Paste query SELECT * FROM order o LEFT JOIN ordermenu om ON o.OrderID = om.OrderID LEFT JOIN menu m ON m.MenuID = om.MenuID WHERE o.CustomerID = $customerId in phpMyAdmin but change parameter $customerId for customerID with orders from your customers table

Comment: Nope, still get the error. it says `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o LEFT JOIN ordermenu om ON o.OrderID = om.OrderID LEFT JOIN menu m ON m.M' at line 1 `

Comment: OK, the problem is that "order" is the word restricted for mysql. You need to add "`" before and after "order" word